# Vowel count only for one word?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a program which asks the user for a friend's name and then the user's name.  It then tells them how many vowels are in the names but my code only counts in number of vowels in one of the words:

```
vowel_list = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
friend_name = input("enter your friends name")
yourname = input("enter your name")

def awesome(yourname,friend_name):
    vowel_count = 0
    friend_name = list(friend_name)
    yourname = list(yourname)
    for i in range(len(yourname)):
        if yourname[i] in vowel_list:
            vowel_count += 1
    return vowel_count
    for i in range(len(friend_name)):
        if me[i] in vowel_list:
            vowel_count += 1
    return vowel_count

print(awesome(yourname,friend_name))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two `return` statements in your function. All code after the first will never be executed.

Just write a function for one name:

```
vowels = set(["a","e","i","o","u"])
def awesome(name):
    vowel_count = 0
    for letter in name:
        if letter in vowels:
            vowel_count += 1
    return vowel_count
```

and use it for both names:

```
friend_name = input("enter your friends name")
yourname = input("enter your name")
print(awesome(friend_name))
print(awesome(yourname))
```